# Checking Checkbox in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview, checkbox

I am trying to check a `CheckBox` for certain rows in a `GridView` if there are records in the database. Lets say I have product 1,2,3,4 in a category and the products available for packaging are 1 and 3. Inside my `GridView`, for each category, I only checked the checkbox of product 1 and 3 instead of all the products in that category. Here is how I set up my `GridView`:

```
<!-- Collapsible panel extender body -->
<asp:Panel ID="pBody1" runat="server" CssClass="cpBody">
    <asp:Label ID="lblBodyText1" runat="server" />
    <!-- Grid view to show products based on each category -->
    <asp:GridView ID="gvProduct" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="998px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" ShowHeader="False" DataKeyNames="id">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelect" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="750px" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="categoryName" HeaderText="Category" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="inventoryQuantity" HeaderText="Quantity" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
```

And from the code behind, first I get all the products based on category. I named it as prodList. Then, I get all the products available for packaging. I named it as distSPUItemList. I loop thru both lists and if their name match, I get the row and check the checkbox:

```
List<ProductPacking> prodList = new List<ProductPacking>();
//Get all products based on category
prodList = prodPackBLL.getAllProductByCategory(category);
gv.DataSource = prodList;
gv.DataBind();

List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems> distSPUItemList = new List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems>();
distSPUItemList = packBLL.getAllSPUItemByDistributionID(distributionID);
for (int i = 0; i < distSPUItemList.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < prodList.Count; j++)
    {
        GridView gvForCheckBox = (GridView)e.Item.FindControl("gvProduct") as GridView;
        foreach (GridViewRow gr in gvForCheckBox.Rows)
        {
            if (prodList[j].name == distSPUItemList[i].name)
            {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.Cells[0].FindControl("cbSelect");
                cb.Checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, for the `CheckBox`, it just checks all the products inside that category instead of checking the one that match between prodList and distSPUItemList. Why is this?

Comment: Does your `ProductPacking` class have a boolean property indicating it is available for packaging? Are you able to add one? If so, you may be able to set the checkbox "Checked attribute" during Data Binding.

Comment: No no what I am trying to do is I got a list of products. And I also got a list of standard packing unit items. If the product is inside the standard packing unit item list for certain distribution, then the checkbox of that product will be checked. That's why I lopped thru both list to match the name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the best way to solve your problem is to determine if this `CheckBox` should be checked prior to Data Binding your "gvProduct" control. Setting this value in the `Data Source` ahead of time will prevent you from having to re-access the `GridView` later on.

If this is not an option, the solution below will work, but is more clunky since you have to re-access the `GridView` and then iterate its Row collection.

Disclaimer, done in my head without VS2012, so please forgive any minor syntax errors. I modified your code to remove parts that were not specifically relevant to this solution. First, get your two lists of objects:

```
List<ProductPacking> prodList = prodPackBLL.getAllProductByCategory(category);
List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems> distSPUItemList = packBLL.getAllSPUItemByDistributionID(distributionID);
```

Next, you can use a simple LINQ query to compare lists of objects finding `ProductPacking` objects whose name property are equal to the items in distSPUItemList. This creates a new collection of only objects that match:

```
var available = // Start with prodList
                from a in prodList 
                // perform an inner-join between prodList and distSPUItemList only returning objects whose names match
                // (x => x.name == a.name) compares b.name to a.name, this is specifically what enforces that names match.
                from b in distSPUItemList.Where(x => x.name == a.name)
                // after inner joining is done, only select objects from prodList (we could select more things, but we only need these.)
                select a;
```

And lastly, you may iterate the gridview rows and see if the name property shown in the GridView was in the list of products available for packaging, if it was, mark the checkbox checked.

```
GridView gvForCheckBox = (GridView)e.Item.FindControl("gvProduct") as GridView;
foreach (GridViewRow gr in gvForCheckBox.Rows)
{
    // query the available collection to see if it contains a ProductPacking object with a name equal to what is in the current GridView row.
    // I would recommend to match on a PK
    // disclaimer, matching on name may be a problem if two different products can have the same name.
    if (available.Where(x=>x.Name==gr.Cells[1].Text).Any())
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.Cells[0].FindControl("cbSelect");
        cb.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does (x => x.name == a.name) select a; means?

Comment: I wrote this solution to be a copy & replace for your three nested for-loops. Can you try my second & third codeblocks and see if it has the desired results? The first codeblock is already being done in your code.

Comment: This is LINQ (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx), it provides syntax for querying objects like Lists and IEnumerables. "Select a;" means literally select objects from the List aliased as "a", which is a `List<ProductPacking> prodList;`

Comment: Yup it works but I need to be clear on the LINQ query so that I can use it in future. Can I explain in this way: The loop items of listSPUItem is store as var x. Then if loop item of name of a which is prodList equals to var x which is loop item of listSPUItem, then I get the a.name?? Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Im glad it worked. I added some comments to the LINQ code. A good description would be "Find all ProductPacking objects whose name occurs in distSPUItemList; from those ProductPacking objects found update GridView's corresponding CheckBox to indicate packaging is available."

Comment: Hello are you still there? I have another question regarding to LINQ query.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44106/discussion-between-david-r-and-gwen)